# Error using dir Function is not defined for 'string' inputs

Tags: string, matlab

I'm writing my first Matlab script, and I get an error trying to use dir().  This is the script:

```
strLocation = "C:\Users\myname\Documents\MATLAB";
listing = dir(strLocation)
```

The error is:

> ```
> Error using dir
> Function is not defined for 'string' inputs.
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should first be noted that a **`char` vector** and a **`string`** are [different things](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html) in Matlab. The `string` data type was introduced recently (in R2016b, I think). Previous versions do not support the `string` type, only `char` vectors.

Since the `string` data type was introduced, many built-in functions that used to accept `char` vector input can now accept `string` input as well. But this is being **gradually** incorporated into functions, apparently. So, even if your Matlab version supports the `string` data type, you may find some functions that still can only take a `char` vector as input. This seems to the case for `dir` in your version. In R2018b `dir` supports both types of input, according to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html).

So, you need to define the input to `dir` as a `char` vector. For this you use `'` instead of `"`:

```
strLocation = 'C:\Users\myname\Documents\MATLAB';
listing = dir(strLocation)
```

Or, if you must have a string, convert it to a `char` vector before passing it to `dir`:

```
strLocation = "C:\Users\myname\Documents\MATLAB";
listing = dir(char(strLocation))
```

Comment: Thank you.  The single quotes work.  But the MATLAB documentation for dir() explicitly tells me to use double quotes: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html  Is the documentation just wrong?  Or am I misreading it?

Comment: It's probably a version-releated issue. The `string` data type is rather new in Matlab, and support for it is being gradually introduced in functions. In R2018b, which is what the documentation refers to now, it should work. In older versions it may not. For example, in my R2017b it does not

Comment: Yes, like @LuisMendo mentioned the online help refers to the latest version. Try running the inside MATLAB instead if you're using an older version.

Comment: Okay, use the 'doc' in MATLAB for version-specific documentation.  That's what I have to do.  Thanks for all the helpful advice.

Answer (score 2):

Since MATLAB R2017a double quotation marks denotes strings and single quotation marks denotes character vectors.

The dir function requires a char vector so you should call it with single quotation marks,

```
strLocation = 'C:\Users\myname\Documents\MATLAB';
listing = dir(strLocation)
```

Comment: Okay, strings and character vectors are different.  Thank you.  How would I figure this out on my own?  The MATLAB documentation here https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html clearly tells me to use double quotes.  It says: For example, dir("FolderName").